# ASP NET CORE - ANGULAR NO 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

This question may be asked many times but the solutions available online are not working for me.

In our project we have as Asp.Net Page with the WebMethod that that handles database, or if I put it this way we have a WebApi as:-

`http://server/Pages/ApplicationData.aspx/GetApplicationLookups`

Now we have an AspNet Core Angular web application which calls that this API

```ts
postgetGetApplicationLookups(url: string) {
    var headers = new Headers();
    headers.set('Accept', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    headers.set('content-Type', 'application/json; charset=utf-8');
    let data = {};
    debugger;
    return this.http.post(
        url,
        data,
        { headers: headers }
    )
        .map(this.handleSuccess)
        .catch(this.handleError)
}
```

I get the following error:-
[image]]

This POST Call works fine if I work with POSTMAN:-

[image]

I modified my Startup.cs with the following code but I am still getting the same error.

```cs
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddCors(options => options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p => p.AllowAnyOrigin()           //Fix API ISSUE
                                                                    .AllowAnyMethod()               //Fix API ISSUE
                                                                     .AllowAnyHeader()));           //Fix API ISSUE


        services.AddMvc();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseWebpackDevMiddleware(new WebpackDevMiddlewareOptions
            {
                HotModuleReplacement = true
            });
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseCors("AllowAll");        

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

            routes.MapSpaFallbackRoute(
                name: "spa-fallback",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
        });
    }
```

My error is :

> Failed to load http://server/Pages/ApplicationData.aspx/GetApplicationLookups: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:60602' is therefore not allowed access.

Any ideas that what I may be missing.

Thanks

Answer (score 17):

Order matters when adding things to the *StartUp.cs*.

In the `ConfigureServices` function, you need to have the `AddMvc` call *after* the `AddCors` call.

```
services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAll", p =>
    {
        p.AllowAnyOrigin()
        .AllowAnyHeader()
        .AllowAnyMethod();
    });
});
...
services.AddMvc(); // must be after AddCors
```

In the `Configure` function, just use one `UseCors` call:

```
app.UseCors("AllowAll");
app.UseMvc();
```

And, make sure that is called before the `UseMvc` call, too.

Comment: Hi, I tried the same URL from the same server through POSTMAN and it works. Later I added a GET request method and it does not work from my project i.e. Visual studio 2017. 
I tried to change the server and at every server with all different accounts and it does not work.

Comment: I don’t know how postman works, I don’t use it. However, I do know about ASP.NET and Cors, and how to set it up so that when you run it, it can received requests, and you will not get the Cors errors. Cors access is configured on the server, not the client. So, in your situation, if the server you’re posting to isn’t set up to receive calls from localhost, it will not work.

Comment: Thanks R.Richards for all the help, but I think you did not read my question properly. I mentioned in the beginning of my post explicitly that Asp. Net core Application is the CLIENT APPLICATION which is calling a WebMethod written in Asp.Net Page in another application. All I was asking that what changes need to be done in that Asp.Net Page (which in this case is my server).

Comment: Then this answer is almost useless to you. My comment is still relevant, the server you are calling needs to allow you to connect from localhost, or what ever server your code runs on. If the server doesn't allow that, you're done.

Comment: Well this worked for me.  Thank you for the answer. I also would like to know how to fix it from the Angular call side.  The funny thing is my Angular Get call works for one object type called Cities, but then I get the CORS error for an obect type called Countries.  Exact same architecture on both ends.  But I had to use this fix  for the latter.  Stumped on why but glad I got it working.